# How to use webservice using json

Tags: android, json

I want to use webservice to get data from after click on my button(button1)unfortunatly stopped I'm using json my debugger is not coming onclick view and my json is not giving response.

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private static final String about = "about"; 
private static String url = "http://www.mydomain/staticinfo";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "id"; 
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS1="success";


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
    .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork()
    .penaltyLog().build());
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();
}
public void action(View v)
{
    if(v.getId()==R.id.button1)
        new aboutAccess().execute();
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "This is demo for smlsolution", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
class aboutAccess extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    private String id;
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
         //String url = "http://10.0.2.2/about.php";
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        String ID="1";
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id ","ID"));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url,"POST", params);
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
        try{
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                flag=0; 
                  String abt=json.getString(about);
                  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),About.class);
                  i.putExtra("about", abt);
                  startActivity(i);
            }
            else{
                flag=1;
            }
        } 
         catch (JSONException e){
             e.printStackTrace(); 
             System.out.println(e.toString());
         }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if(flag==1)
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the logcat error along with line number.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Your app is crashing because you are doing `Activity` switching operations in the `doInBackground()`. Change the following piece of code from `doInBackground()` to `onPostExecute()`,

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AboutUs.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Do something like below,

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if(flag==1)
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please Enter Correct informations",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else{
             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AboutUs.class);
             startActivity(i);
             finish();
               }
        }
```